# Telerik Treeview control disable lowest level options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, treeview

I have a Telerik Treeview and it has 4 levels, each node has a checkbox.  I need to disable or make readonly the lowest level of the tree.  The items in that level are really there to show the user what is in the last branch, but they get all or none.  Currently I am binding the tree like this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView().Name("OriginTree").BindTo(Model.OriginTree).Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes.Name("OriginChecks").CheckChildren(true)))
```

I'm fairly new to MVC (5) and this is my first attempt with Telerik controls.  Any advice or links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that when building the TreeViewItemModel (which is what gets bound to the Treeview) that you can enable and disable each one, so when building the lowest level, I just set all the Enabled flags to false, similar to how you can set which check boxes are pre-selected.

Very easy once you understand more how the treeview works.